# react-datepicker fails to set default value on load

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

datepicker in my Meteor/React app and I can't find a way to set/update state to get default value be loaded from the props.

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export default class AddDate extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: this.props.start.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        };
    }

    handleStartDate(date) {
        this.setState({ 
            startDate: date
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleStartDate.bind(this)} 
            className="form-control" 
            id="startDate"
            todayButton={"Get Today's Date"} />
        );
    }
}

AddDate.propTypes = {
  start: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Initially, the props come from the Fullcalendar "select" event, which provides (start, end).

The error I get is: "Uncaught TypeError: t.date.clone is not a function"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `startDate` prop [should be a (moment) object](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md#startdate), not a string. No need to `format()` it.

```js
import moment from "moment";

// ...

this.state = {
  startDate: moment(this.props.start),
};
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Now when I click on the input field, it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: mom.clone(...).stripZone is not a function" and doesn't open the popup datepicker.

Comment: Hard to find the issue from here. Could you check if the `start` prop is a moment object by logging it to the console? If not maybe try `startDate: moment(this.props.start)`.

Comment: Both things you suggested were correct ones and the issue is fixed. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.